# Как получить href в данном случае?

Tags: javascript

Есть множество:

```
<ul id="btn-subdl">
  <li><a href="1">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">Ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```

Как получить href и текст из  в самом первом теге li ?

Comment: Откуда получить?

Comment: Из тегов получить

Comment: По какому событию?

Comment: В каком смысле? Я все написал в вопросе

Comment: Просто функция нужна,которая получит href у первого элемента тега li.

Comment: Интересно, что за массовые дизлайки..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var link = document.querySelector('#btn-subdl > li:first-child > a');
console.log('Link: ' + link.href);
console.log('Attribute: ' + link.getAttribute('href'));
console.log('Text: ' + link.innerText);
```

```html
<ul id="btn-subdl">
  <li><a href="1">Ссылка1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">Ссылка2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">Ссылка3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ну и за что минус?

Comment: Спасибо большое,то что нужно)

Comment: Кто-то прошелся по всем скопом xDDD И да, у вас href "неверно" достается.

Comment: @MedvedevDev Ну непонятно, какой href нужен автору. Но добавил и второй вариант

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = document.querySelector('ul>li>a');
console.log(a.textContent); // Text
console.log(a.href); // href
```

```html
<ul id="btn-subdl">
  <li><a href="#1">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#2">Ссылка 2 </a></li>
  <li><a href="#3">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('a');
// Проходим по всем а
a.forEach(function (e) { 
  //
  e.addEventListener('click', function (ee) { 
      ee.preventDefault(); // Для демо, удалите если надо
       console.log(ee.target.textContent);
  })
})
```

```html
<ul id="btn-subdl">
  <li><a href="1">Ссылка 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">Ссылка 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: "href и текст из в самом первом теге li" - если перевести, то задание просто получить значения: текст и href - ссылки в первом элементе списка.

Comment: @MedvedevDev поправил, после вашего перевода, благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

### Если просто получить значение без какого-либо события:

```js
let target = document.querySelector('#btn-subdl > li:first-child > a');

console.log(target.href); //полная ссылка
console.log(target.getAttribute("href")); //относительная ссылка
console.log(target.text);
```

```html
<ul id="btn-subdl">
  <li><a href="1">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="2">Ссылка</a></li>
  <li><a href="3">Ссылка</a></li>
</ul>
```